# How to encrypt data using server's public key txt file on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa

I'm working on an iOS application with a java server. I need to encrypt some data using RSA. The RSA public key is a txt file. I want to connvert it into a SecKeyRef. The server is developed by the previous guy. I don't have the access to do anything with the server.

```
NSData *keyBytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY options:0];

SecCertificateRef mycertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) keyBytes);
SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
SecTrustRef myTrust;

if (mycertificate != NULL){
OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(mycertificate, myPolicy, &myTrust);
SecTrustResultType trustResult;
if(status == noErr) {
    status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);
}
CFRelease(mycertificate);
CFRelease(myPolicy);
CFRelease(myTrust);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Hell no!");
}
return SecTrustCopyPublicKey(myTrust);
```

The problem is SecCertificateRef is always null. The application crashes when I run the code above!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your certificate to the binary format DER from the text format PEM (Privacy Enhanced Mail, a text format for cryptographic objects). Basically PEM is a header, footer, some options (not used for certificates) and base 64 encoded DER in the middle.

As I didn't find any direct sample that performs this operation in iOS it is probably easiest to convert the certificate yourself from `.txt` to `.bin`, `.der` or `.cer`. You can do this for instance using `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.txt -outform der -out cert.der
```

and then try to read it in using the code in the question.

Comment: Firstly, thank you! Here is one problem. the public key txt file is plain text without -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -------END PUBLIC KEY-----. The format is not the same with public key file with 64 characters each line. I have no idea to deal with it

Comment: @BoqinHu Unsurprisingly - since you haven't described the text file, only what's **not** in there - neither do I.